# Add Header column to Silverlight Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight

Help!!!  I have a grid bound to an observable collection.  I need to have a row appear as the first Item, if and only if there are items in the collection:

```
        <Grid x:Name="Broadcast" Opacity="0.85" MouseEnter="Broadcast_MouseEnter" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Border
            x:Name="broadcastBorder" 
            Opacity="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            BorderThickness="3" 
            BorderBrush="Black" 
            Background="White" 
            CornerRadius="5"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="0"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <ListBox Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="icAlerts" Grid.Row="1" >
                <!--<TextBlock Text="Clear All" />
                        <Button Tag="" Content="X" Click="DeleteBroadcast_Click" />-->
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Background="Red" x:Name="spAlerts" Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Border>
                            <ScrollViewer>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListBox.Template>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Stroke="LightGray" StrokeThickness="2" 
                                       RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" Margin="15"
                                       Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                            </Rectangle>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}" />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Tag="{Binding}" Content="X" Click="DeleteBroadcast_Click"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

BroadcastMessages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
BroadcastMessages.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(BroadcastMessages_CollectionChanged);
            icAlerts.ItemsSource = BroadcastMessages;
```

How can I make the first row appear like a "header" row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just ended up modifying the ObservableList before the delegate call.  Turns out we are running away from Silverlight . . .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you just don't want to use the header row? There isn't much you can't do with it. Bellow I added filtering to a grid, including text boxes, combo boxes and a date picker.

If you still want it to be in a data row then you could bring back your data, and if there is any data add another row but where a "type" property or something is different. Then your binding converters would change the appearance based on this "type" property. You would bind to the collection sorted so the added row is first.

[image: DataGrid filtering]

Comment: a header row would work fine for me, I need it to be actionable as I need a "clear all" button.  As a total Silverlight n00b, how could I modify the above code.  My googling has indicated that I might need to completely rewrite the display of the data (as the ObservableList is used across multiple different lists), and I really don't want to have to do that